# JSX syntax inside the return function of a component causing a blank white screen on the browser

Tags: reactjs, components, mern

this is a component of a mern crud app. Post creation works and were displaying on the browser and mongo DB. but while implementing update, JSX of one of the component is causing the app to crash. Please check the following component

```
import React from 'react'
import Post from './Post/Post'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Posts = ({ setCurrentId }) => {

  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);


 console.log(posts);
  return (
    !posts.length ? "No Posts, Make a post and come back" : (
      <div className='outer'>
        {
          posts.map((post)=>(
            <div className = 'inner' key= {post._id}>
            <Post post = {post} setCurrentId = {setCurrentId} />
            </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    )      
)      
}
```

I am getting these errors ONLY in console, visual code does not show any error for client and server side.
[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGBSu.png)

hit and trial :
if I comment out everything inside the outer div, I can see part of the app(one component of two components in the App.js), if I paste it back I can see the whole app, but when I refresh it goes back to black white screen.

guys plese let me know whats causing this, I guessing it is to do with the syntax, but I tried a lot o things but still not working.

Comment: Your error shows its coming from `Post.js` which I'm assuming is the `Post` component and not the one you're showing us. Perhaps you're not accessing the prop correctly?

Comment: Hi Brian, sorry missed your cmment, Post component is basically the structure of the output, parent Posts is passing through props to child Post which is only displaying the info on the browser within a structure. As I mentioned in the question, If i comment out everthing inside the Posts commponent output is partially displayed, when un comment it I can see the complete page, but if I refresh it goes back to blank white screen.

Comment: In the console where it's showing the error, click the link for `Post.js`. If your dev source maps are setup correctly, it should show you exactly what code is causing the problem. I still think you're showing us the wrong code in relation to this error

Comment: console error is showing as posts.map((post)) is not a valid function, I saw other questions online, I tried IIFE's and used a for loop, for in loops, by using the IIFE's there are no more console errors, but still browser does not render anything. What I found troubleshooting this issue is, that in the expression const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);,  posts stores an array of objects that can be logged to the console, but when posts array is used inside the return function, there is nothing inside it as can be seen in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a component your return need to be XML (JSX = JS + XML)

So, your return must be begin by a  and finish by the close of the same element .

In your case :

```
return (
<> //this is fragment, see react doc for that
 {productsData.map((product) => {
    return (
      <>
        {posts.length === 0 ? 
          "No Posts, Make a post and come back"
        : (
          <div className="outer">
            {posts.map((post) => (
              <div className="inner" key={post._id}>
                <Post post={post} setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    );
  })}
</>
)
```

Comment: Hey Luther, thanks for the prompt reply and your suggestion, I have tried putting all the return code within ( inside one div or fragment, still it does not work and shows a blank screen )

Comment: Sorry, so prompt ! Edit normaly work

Comment: tried the above code, still the same, nothing renders in the browser.

Comment: @LutherW a string is a valid return type for a component.

Answer (score 0):

Does state.posts exist in your store?
And you need to return a JSX element, always

To have a safe render, try;

```
import React from "react";
import Post from "./Post/Post";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import "./Posts.css";

const Posts = ({ setCurrentId }) => {
    const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
    console.log(posts);
    return (
       <>
           {(posts.map = (post) => {
               let obj = {
                   post: { post },
                   setCurrentId: { setCurrentId }
               };
               return <Post obj={obj} />
           }
           )}
       </>
   );
};

export default Posts;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, I tried your code but output is not rendering on the browser, console.log statement returns data in the console(for that I had to comment out everything inside return, when I paste it back, then I can see the output, but if I refresh the browser it goes back to blank page).

Comment: https://github.com/ash2686/CsvBox  is the git repo.

Comment: can i see your redux store that contains the post?
and also, the github repo does not contain the react project

Comment: sorry about posting blank react section, I created a new repo but somehow react part did not get uploaded, here is is react part of the project: https://github.com/ash2686/CSV-react

Comment: try that out now

Comment: still no go, I did try sending props as an object, unfortunately still not working, no errors on the react side, no errors on the node.js side, now not even getting any error in the console.  I can see the form part but Posts/Post is not displayed, If I enter something in the form they are getting saved in MongoDB, sometimes I am getting Posts/Post displayed randomly buy moving or deleting things, but display goes away when browser is refreshed.

Comment: there is something wrong with the communication between <Posts> and <Post>, I hv tried so many different ways, I am starting to wonder if the problem lies else where, but hv not clue where

Comment: since it's an api, you use hooks to fetch the data everytime the component mounts, like

```
...
useEffect(() => {
  fetch_data_to_store()
}, [])
...
```